# Can I switch to DSL if I already have a T1 line?

Tags: dsl, t1

I am a software engineer working remotely over a T1 line from home. I live in a very rural location and pay $500/month for this line. At the time, I had no choice. They had to install a series of repeaters over a 7 mile stretch for my T1.

My question is: Since I have this T1 line now, when my contract is up can I switch to a DSL provider which would obviously be less expensive?

I am thinking it would work over the same trunk with those repeaters, but I don't have enough knowledge in this area to know for sure and I'm not sure I can trust the provider to answer me honestly. Though I've not asked yet.

Comment: T1 is an ambiguous term. Please clarify the actual technology used.

Comment: Not sure how T1 is ambiguous. I have 1.5Mbps up and 1.5Mbps down over copper wires running through repeaters from the CO to my home office. I suppose you could wonder whether it is copper or fiber, but mine is copper.

Comment: Yes, DSL also uses copper and so does USB. Like just about anything wired. These days, T1 is more of a speed specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For almost all telcos nowadays, modern T1 *service* is actually provided using **HDSL** (or HDSL2 or HDSL4) equipment.  Traditional T1 requires that the two copper pairs to be conditioned lines (e.g. bridged taps have to be removed), whereas xDSL does not.  HDSL has been replacing traditional T1 equipment since the mid 1990s, as HDSL is easier and less expensive to install and maintain.

By "DSL" you presumably mean **ADSL**. All xDSL technologies are distance limited, but may be extended with "amplifier" or repeater/regeneration units.  Apparently there are ADSL "repeaters" according to this [wikipedia article on ADSL loop extender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADSL_loop_extender).  There is a limit to the number of "repeaters" that can be installed.  An older generation of HDSL repeaters was limited to 2 units, and the next generation (that I worked on) allowed three (which could cover the 7 miles in your case).

> I am thinking it would work over the same trunk with those repeaters.

It's not a *"trunk"*, but one or two pairs of copper wire.  ADSL and POTS (plain old telephone service, i.e. voice) would only use one pair.
The T1 or HDSL repeaters are not reusable or adaptable for ADSL.

> Since I have this T1 line now, when my contract is up can I switch to a DSL provider which would obviously be less expensive?

Only your telco can answer this question.  A change in service would require equipment replacement at multiple locations, so a *"DSL provider"* cannot just step in like in an urban situation.

Perhaps you could renegotiate the price of the T1 service, assuming that the cost of the original installation was amortized and now paid back.  Back in the day I was told that telcos were still billing for T1 service as if they were still using expensive traditional T1 equipment, even though the replacement HDSL had *significantly* lowered their costs.

Comment: Thanks @sawdust, hopefully the amortization has been paid back, as you state above. I'd like more throughput for less money, but wouldn't we all. :)

Answer (score 0):

DSL and T1 are different things.

DSL comes in to your home over normal phone wiring.  Among other factors, the further you are from the phone company's central office, the lower your maximum speed is.  It's possible you are too far from the phone company to support any DSL speed higher than dial-up speeds.  If your nearest neighbors cannot get DSL, you probably won't either.

I haven't worked with T1's before and am not sure how they work on the provider end, but I'm certain the equipment on the provider end to provide DSL and T1 are different, even if T1 wiring is similar to phone line wiring (some Google searches seemed to suggest that).  Assuming the same company provides your T1 and DSL, they may not be able to simply plug your T1 into their DSL equipment and magically give you DSL.

So it may not be a simple thing on the provider end to simply send DSL over the T1 wiring coming in to your location.

Comment: *"if T1 wiring is similar to phone line wiring"* -- Traditional T1 (and HDSL) uses 2 copper pairs, whereas ADSL uses only 1 pair (as well as SHDSL).  Real T1 requires that the two pairs to be conditioned lines (e.g. bridge taps have to be removed), whereas HDSL (T1 replacement) and ADSL do not.