# Using a dedicated landline for internet?

Tags: networking, voip, wired-networking, dsl

as I'm sure many of you already know. Landline connections can be used for internet over DSL and VDSL e.c.t. So I want to know, is it possible to use a dedicated landline connection for internet with a DSL modem without any kind of internet package.

Thanks

For improved clarification: The scenario is a point of one having a dedicated home landline without an internet connection being explicitly provided by the landline provider.

My theory is that if you can get an internet package from the same network cabling that is providing you with landline service, surely, without an internet package through cable, that you have some kind of internet connectivity - or at least itranet connectivity to the landline provider since it was possible to provide an internet connection initially. And that most telephone networks are digitally switched (Originally done by the infamous analogue switch board).

So even without an internet package via cable, but still having a dedicated lineline, the purpose of this thread is to ask what can be done with this.

As the very helpful answers have pointed out here, it can depend on multiple factors so leaves me with more questions than I started this thread with :D

Comment: Short answer, No.

Comment: And the long answer?

Comment: Same as the short answer

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "no internet package"?

Comment: T1 service (or E1) is the traditional data connection offered to businesses by telcos over twisted pair.  [HDSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bit-rate_digital_subscriber_line), HDSL2, and HDSL4 are typically used to implement such T1/E1 connections.  Presumabaly by *"DSL"* you are referring to ADSL for residential clients?

Comment: So by no internet package I mean that the ISP (But not technically ISP since they are not providing internet, perhaps landline provider would be the correct term) provides only a phone line to the house, that you would use for calling. I wonder if it is possible to use this connection for internet connectivity; however limited in functionality for some kind of what you would consider internet access (Having an IP, requiring packet routing and being able to target a particular service somewhere outside of your own home or 'LAN') this service may be limited to VOIP but that's the point of ^.

Comment: @JamesHopwood: Ah, in that case you're _physically_ not connected to a device that could provide you a DSL signal (a "DSLAM", or its VDSL equivalent), so Albin's answer is correct. (Keep in mind that DSL only uses telephone _wiring_, it doesn't actually go over the telephone network!)

Comment: @user1686 what's a DSLAM - VDSL equivalent? I'm curious, as far as I know - and I just know the basics - DSLAM isn't specific to a certain DSL signal (ADSL, SDSL, VDSL and whatever else there is).

Comment: @sawdust Yes, I was referring to residential clients.  So besides business usually having a one too one upload, download ratio is there a technical difference between the business provided HDSL* and residential provided ADSL?

Comment: @Albin: No idea, I just remember being told that it's not called that in VDSL anymore.

Comment: @JamesHopwood -- ADSL and T1 are different services provided by the telco.  See [my answer to this question](https://superuser.com/questions/845313/can-i-switch-to-dsl-if-i-already-have-a-t1-line).  Re "w/o internet package"*: telcos offer a [leased line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leased_line) which is typically used by businesses to connect remote sites/buildings with private voice & data links.  If you could afford a leased line to the CO, then only the telco could tell you what connection options are available.

Comment: You seem to be equating this to plugging in a TV arial to get free-to-air programmes. There is no Internet equivalent of free-to-air. Unless you have an ISP at the other end of your line waiting to hear from you… you have nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Short: no.

Long: Given a analog phone line, if you do not order DSL over your phone line your will either receive no DSL signal at all or you won't have get the necessary credentials to access it. You could connect through an analogue signal via a regular modem (56k !!) to a server that is connected to the internet. If your area still has ISDN lines it will be up to 254k.

If you have IP-telephony in your area you'll actually get internet over your phone line, but it will be restricted to voice services. But I have now I idea if you can operate a modem over a IP-based phone line at all. And if you do what compression would be possible...

Anyway, where's the goal in this whole project?

Comment: Well, I was wondering to know how much is possible through a dedicated phone line without an internet package on that line. Seeing how much Virgin Media has been dropping out recently made me wonder how much redundancy I could have, since I have the 'fibre' package which only makes use of a Coaxial cable, DOCSIS 3.0 standard, and there is Landline sockets all over the house which I remember using for Internet in my student housing last year, It left me curious in finding out just how much I can do on a landline connection without a internet package.

Comment: I think your explanation answers it pretty well, obviously, without an internet package making use of the phone line, I didn't expect much would be possible but since I know that telephones are routed over VOIP networks now; I know they must have some form of internet access if they are being given IP's and being routed digitally.

But if it is the case that in some areas IP-telephony is used, why does the landline not require a modem if it is being given digital and not analogue signals?

Comment: @JamesHopwood It's a little bit more complicated and it depends on your service provider and the infrastructure used and on the actual signal that comes out from your wall. Usually you subscribe for phone+internet, then you get the router that can handel both. I honestly don't know what kind of device if any you get if you just order phone. It might very well be that you get a "phone-only-device", or you just get the phone signal directly without the internet signal and the conversion to IP-telephony is made outside your home (possibly at the DSLAM location).

Comment: @JamesHopwood But if you ask your provider what "happens" if you cancel the Internet and just order a phone line, let us know, I'm curious. You might find [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_subscriber_line) and [this](https://computer.howstuffworks.com/dsl.htm) interesting (and helpful for a better understanding)

Comment: @JamesHopwood feel free to accept my answer if it answered your question.

Comment: Would do but unfortunately, this thread is answer locked because the thread is not well clarified. :/ But yes, will do, thank you for the info.

Comment: so as you say when it is a phone only device and they move the IP conversion to their own location. However unrealistic, does that not mean that there could be a way to modulate a telephone signal in a way that manipulates the DSLAM location into performing IP based network operations. Perhaps Dial up?

My expertise on some of these areas is rather shallow but I'm just guessing based on what little I know here. And yes, I wouldn't consider using dial up, ever. But just want to know if something like this is possible.

Comment: @JamesHopwood FYI you can [still accept (and vote) on the answers of a closed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91827/can-an-answer-of-a-closed-question-be-accepted). I'm not sure about your last question, what exactly do you want to do?